# How to return data from a Threading Task

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

I am currently trying to use a .net Task to run a long method.  I need to be able to return data from the task.  I would like to call this method multiple times each time running it in a new task.  However, returning data using the Task.Result property makes each task wait until complete.

For example currently if do something like this :

```
public void RunTask()
{
   var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
   { 
      return LongMethod() 
   });  

   Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
}
```

and call it multiple times, each time taking a different amount of time, it is waits for each Task to complete before executing the next.

Is it possible to call my RunTask method multiple times, each time returning a result without having to wait for each task to complete in order ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  When you call `task.Result` on a `Task<T>`, it will block until a result occurs.

If you want to make this completely asynchronous, you could either change your method to return the `Task<T>` directly, and "block" at the caller's level, or use a continuation:

```
public void RunTask()
{
   var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
   { 
      return LongMethod() 
   });  

   // This task will run after the first has completed...
   task.ContinueWith( t =>
       {
           Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
       });
}
```

Comment: Ah I understand the continuation now. That accomplishes what I need.  Thanks.